# No warning but wrong if the global variable is the same as the INOUT variable in a subroutine

Tags: fortran

I have a question about global and local variables.

I know that if a variable `var` is a global variable, I should not have `REAL*8, INTENT(INOUT) :: var` in a subroutine at the same time.

But I just accidentally did that, and there is no warning. Sometimes the code runs well, but sometimes there are big mistakes. My understanding is that in some cases the value of `var` is randomly assigned when the subroutine ends, usually very big numbers in my results. So even if there is no warning, I should definitely avoid this happen again.

I am not sure whether my understanding is correct or not. Looking forward to any comment! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid your understanding is not correct, and there are almost certainly bugs elsewhere in your program - probably. I say probably beacuse you haven't included code showing your problem. Without this code I have to guess about some of what you are saying, please in future always include a complete code which shows your problem, it makes answering easier and answers more accurate.

Anyway firstly please don't use real*8. It is not part of Fortran. It has never been part of Fortran. You can not rely on it to do what you expect.

Secondly there is no reason within standard Fortran that you can't have a local variable with the same name as one accessed by host association (I am guessing this is what you mean by a global variable, but the standard doesn't use that term to my knowledge). Consider the following program. You can see that in the subroutine bar the local foo is accessed, while in the main program it is the module variable foo. All works as expected:

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran-8 --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat scope.f90 
Module module_scope

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only :  wp => real64

  Implicit None

  Real( wp ) :: foo

Contains

  Subroutine bar( foo )

    Real( wp ), Intent( In ) :: foo

    Write( *, * ) foo

  End Subroutine bar

End Module module_scope

Program testit

  Use module_scope, Only : wp, foo, bar

  Implicit None

  foo = 6.0_wp
  Write( *, * ) 'foo = ', foo

  Call bar( 5.0_wp )
  Call bar( 3.0_wp )
  Call bar( 2.0_wp )

End Program testit
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran-8 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=f2008 -fcheck=all scope.f90 
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 foo =    6.0000000000000000     
   5.0000000000000000     
   3.0000000000000000     
   2.0000000000000000
```

Note I am not saying this is good practice - in fact I think it horrible. But it is not wrong.

Thus if your program is not behaving as you expect and I have guessed correctly what you are describing, well you will have to look for the error elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Ian Bush, thank you very much for your reply and example. I learned a lot from it! I will check my code. Thanks again!